# If $f$ is uniformly continuous, how can I show that $g$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

1. $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions
2. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\quad ;\quad g(x)\neq 0\quad$; $\quad g$ is bounded
3. $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} =1$$

If $f$ is uniformly continuous, how can I show that $g$ is uniformly continuous too? 
Someone has given a wrong counterexample to show that the question is wrong by comparing $-x$ and $e^{-x}$. Why is this counterexample wrong to show my question is wrong?Because I have already said that condition $3$ stated in question should hold for it to be true.The counterexample stated does not fulfill the $3$rd condition since it is wrong hence does not prove anything.
Someone else has claimed the question is false without giving proper reason for why my question should provide information about "what happens to $\frac{f}{g}$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$"

What I have tried?
$$\forall\epsilon\hspace{3mm}\exists c\hspace{3mm} \forall x:\hspace{3mm}\left\| \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-1 \right\|<\epsilon$$
$$\implies \hspace{3mm}\left\| \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)} \right\|<\epsilon$$
$$\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}\quad; \quad  \frac{g(x)}{2}<f(x)<\frac{3}{2}g(x)$$

I have no idea on how to use second condition $2$ in favor of solving the problem.

The working example would be consider both $f$ and $g$ functions to be 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
I could not find an example in which $f$ and $g$ would be different functions that fulfills the question conditions.

Comment: The claim is false. Perhaps the following example is illuminating. Let $f(x)=2+\sin x$ for all $x$, and $g(x)=2+\sin x$ when $x\ge0$ and $g(x)=2+\sin(x^2)$ when $x<0$. Then $f$ and $g$ are continuous everywhere, their values are in the bounded interval $[1,3]$, $f(x)/g(x)=1$ for all $x>0$, $f$ is uniformly continuous on all of $\Bbb{R}$ by the mean value theorem. Yet $g(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R}$ because $\sin(x^2)$ oscillates more and more violently as $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: Really, the problem is that condition 3. only says something about the asymptotic behavior of $g$ when $x\to\infty$. We can change the definition of $g$ in any interval of the form $(-\infty,c]$ without affecting this condition, and ruin uniform continuity (as long as we observe continuity and boundedness). Please check the original form of the exercise. Something must be missing? Possibly you only need uniform continuity of $g$ in $[0,\infty)$? Where did you find this problem anyway?

Answer (score 5):

HINT: $|\frac12f(x)|\leq|g(x)|\leq\frac32|f(x)|$ for large $x$.

Some additional assumptions about behaviour at $-\infty$ are needed, e.g. $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$, because without it the thesis is not true: compare $-x$ and $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @FreeMind The definition of limit with $\varepsilon=\frac12$.

Answer (score 3):

You forget to say what happens to $f/g$ as $x \to -\infty$ so the assertion is false.

Comment: The question was stated for $\infty$ only. No condition was stated for $-\infty$

Comment: under what condition the assertion would be true?